# Facebook like box and the new timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-timeline

I have a problem with the new facebook timeline and the like box from my site.

For example: if you click like on this website http://www.roflplanet.com/962/ the like is displayed on the timeline
but if i click like on my website the like isn't displayed http://lolbuzz.net/test

what can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least for now the Timeline seems tempermental as to whether it will show Likes or not. With two test users and one real user of an Open Graph app I tried Liking a few pages on a site I recently completed. At first the posts appeared on the Timeline, but after I hid the test posts from the real user's Timeline using the *Hide from Timeline* option, they never again showed up. I believe it has to do with the way Facebook is attempting to detect spam and unwanted shares with a rank system (if this is the case, it would conceivably also be affected by friends using the *Hide story* or *Report story or spam* options on your Like story when it shows up in their feeds).

However, in the [Like Button documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) Facebook doesn't promise that a story will show in the Timeline, just that Likes will show up in friends news feeds:

> The Like button lets a user share your content with friends on Facebook. When the user clicks the Like button on your site, a story appears in the user's friends' News Feed with a link back to your website.

Comment: Did this help you solve your issue? Would you consider [marking it as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)?

Comment: i would do it but i can't because i don't have enough reputation